# What song is playing in this commercial for "DOOM"?

Tags: identify-this-song, videogame-soundtrack

[This cinematic trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSZ4tSoumNk) for the upcoming game "DOOM" just came out. What song is playing in the background?

Comment: Sounded like Combichrist, guys that did the soundtrack to Devil May Cry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "New Noise" from [Refused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refused). A great song.

Link to youtube here:

[Refused-New noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8MkVIe9xGc)

*I nearly cried when i saw that the song is 18 years old, I am really getting old ;)*